# Where to place the button to open a DataTable and fill input fields based on selection?

Tags: forms, web-app, bootstrap, webforms

I have a wizard that has four steps. On the first step, there is a form with user data inputs. I need to have a button that opens up a modal with a datatable, and based on the selection on that table, the input fields to be filled with that information. 
But I am not sure where to place this button and what design would be best to use so that it looks good. 
This is what it looks like thus far :
[image]

Comment: is the user allowed to enter the First name and last name of these fields, or is it only through the modal once they pick that both are populated?

Comment: If the user is not on the modal, then he is allowed to populate the fields with their data

Comment: okay; so they can either input from selecting thru the modal, or manually input?

Comment: Correct. If I want to add a user and he is on the database, then I just select it through the modal which opens up a datatable. If I want to add a user and  he is not in the database, then I can manually add him by filling out the required inputs in the form

Answer (score 2):

You could use a segmented control, with the default choice being the first choice.

If the user goes to import from the database dialog and there are no results, you can give them an action to manually input, which will close the dialog and switch the control to manually input the user data...

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX3mHj.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! this seems like it would be better ! I'm gonna try it now !
Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 1):

I find the implementation of Dashlane for filling in user data very useful.  It basically 'hangs' underneath the form when information is available. 
[image: Example from the stackexchange sign-up form]
It does appear only when I select the field, probably due to the technical part (which form to fill). It does convey very good what information is filled in.